# How to do a javascript overlay on flash page after loading from html

Tags: javascript, html, flash

I have a flash page which takes quite some time to load, but I want to show something to the user the instant index.html is loaded but I want it to appear on top of the flash content, preferably at the top middle/center and remove/unload the script once the flash starts loading. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks

Comment: check up on flash wmode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as far as I see, you are not able to create a "dialog/overlay" over a flash on most of the browsers( FIREFOX, IE...). so I suggest that you "hide" the div of the flash when the flash is being loaded, and "show" the div of the flash once it's been loaded. e.g.

```
<!-- when flash loading -->
<div id="wrapper_of_flash" style="display:none">
   ... flash element here
</div>
```

Comment: Although this is not what I did, I decided to accept it as the answer since I just did the loading trick on the html instead.